# iOS Performance With Sprites

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm making a health bar for a battle scene in a game with cocos2d. If I was doing this in web design the most optimized way to do it would be a 1px by (height) image of the color I wanted, repeated horizontally as far as I needed it to be. Is this the case with iPhone's as well?

Would it be better, performance-wise, to have 1 small sprite and repeat it multiple times until it's the width I need or would it be better to just have the image of the bar I needed and then scale it down as the monster loses health?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the 1px by height image. Set the scale x property to scale it appropriately to correspond to the health. I'm pretty certain you can scale a sprite to whatever you want and will still use the same amount of memory (don't quote me on that).

Despite this, one full sized sprite isn't going to affect the performance a whole lot, so if you want to use a full image (to make it more detailed than just a box), then it's probably fine.

If you want to use a full sized image and are still worried about performance, put it into a texture atlas (sprite sheet) with all of your other sprites (because you are using texture atlases (sprite sheets), right? ;) ) and render it with a CCBatchNode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've never heard of a texture atlas before... I've been using spritesheets instead. I know this one sprite won't cause performance problems but I wondered what was the best practice. I didn't think about scaling a small sprite to be bigger. That makes alot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome, and a texture atlas **is** a sprite sheet so you are doing fine. :)

Comment: Oh okay great... I was just about to look that up ;)

Comment: My experience doing 2D OpenGL ES is that switching textures is not that big of a performance penalty (UIKit should be doing it all the time, unless the images are being stitched together behind the acenes). Using atlases to minimize texture switch seems to be a preemtive optimization, or 'good practice'. Indiscriminated use of blending has way more impact: iOS devices just can't handle significant overdraw.

Comment: In terms of memory usage, the original sprite and the stretched sprite are equivalent; but the stretched one spans more pixels on screen and hence more overdraw. Of course, a single health bar should 't make that much of a difference.

Comment: @ranReloaded Ok, thanks for the clarification, I felt like what I said was too good to be true. I assume stretching textures is still better than using a larger image? Or no?

Comment: Yes it should be. Textures are stored in memory: the less you use, the better. I'm not sure if the GPU caches the texture read operations for many fragments using the same texel, or it reads once per screen pixel, though.

Comment: If your texture is one pixel wide and a solid color, or a vertical gradient that you stretch horizontally, you can get away with using a colored (not textured) quad. That _should_ be faster as there are no texture reads.